# UPDATE only if field is empty

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla

I am trying to stop 2 tables from being updated based on an update on the first table.

Here is what I have to check the first table.

```
//add user to pif_table//
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query="UPDATE `pif_table` SET $g = '$uname', @success = 1 WHERE $g IS NULL OR $g = '' AND id = '$id' ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->execute();
```

So, the first table, above is updated only if the $g column is empty.

I only wish the next 2 tables to be updated IF, $g column was empty and was updated above.

I receive a syntax error from the @success = 1 part of the command.

```
if ($success == 1){
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query="UPDATE `jospk_users` SET tables = tables +1, payments = payments +1, tbl".$pifbase."= tbl".$pifbase." +1 WHERE id = '$uid'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->execute();

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = "INSERT INTO `pif_payments` (`table_num`, `r_1`, `r_2`, `r_3`, `r_4`, $g, `amount`) VALUES ('$id', '$r1', '$r2', '$r3', '$r4', '$uname', '$pifbase') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $g = '$uname'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the Jommla's JFactory's `execute` method will not return false if the record was not updated and you can only check this if you query the database.

So, create a variable or array with the new value(s) before attempting to run the first `UPDATE` query and once you have, check the record and see if it matches the new value if so keep running the remaining queries.

Comment: $result always returns 1, so that doesn't work.  Thanks for the reply though Keith.

Comment: I'm not sure what $db is here. Can you please show me the code instantiating the `$db` object? The execute method on the PDO object returns a boolean but I want to test with your own code (i.e. if $g is empty)

Comment: $result returns 1, even if the UPDATE was or wasn't done.

Comment: I know. Once you execute the update statement, you need to query the database manually `SELECT` to see if the update was done or not.

Comment: there must be someway to get a 0 or a false from the statement, if it wasn't updated.

Comment: I only briefly looked into the JFactory docs and other questions on this site. As  I understood, as long as the query did not fail you'll get a true response. I think you've already mentioned this.